# df showing wrong disk usage despite the directory is empty

Tags: linux, du, linux-disk-free

When I check the size of used space on my disk on a linux centos 7.4 for directory /logs.

I get as bellow (33M used) with df but with du I get 0:

```
        $ df -h /logs
        Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
        /dev/vdb1       9.4G   33M  9.3G   1% /logs

        But the directory is empty
        $  ll /logs
        total 0

        $ du -sh /logs
        0       /logs

        $ lsof | grep deleted 
          no output
```

I try to umount the /logs , also I try to reboot the VM, but the used size always 33M.

What should I do please?

Comment: what's the filesystem on /dev/vdb1 ?

Comment: And when you do `ls -ltra`? Maybe there are some hidden files.

Comment: @DanielFarrell, it's xfs

Comment: @Dominique                                                                                                          
$  ls -ltra /logs
total 4
dr-xr-xr-x. 21 root root 4096 Apr  3 13:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 maria maria 6 May  3 17:34 .

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/757919/df-says-33mb-is-used-when-there-are-no-files-on-the-partition looks like a perfect match, right up to the 33 MB